# cannot create and run a JAR file

Tags: java

```
package company;

public class Employee{
    private int num;

    public Employee(int newNum) {
       setNum(newNum);
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(int newNum) {
        num = newNum;
    }
}
```

and there is my driver.

```
import company.*;

public class PrintEmployee {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Employee emp;
       emp = new Employee(10000);
       System.out.println(emp.getNum());
   }
}
```

First, I compile Employee.java with `javac *.java`. 
Secondly, I am using `jar -cf company.jar .\*.class` this command to create a JAR file. 
After that, I am using `javac -cp company.jar PrintEmployee.java` this command to compile it but it does not work.

> PrintEmployee.java:1: error: package company does not exist 
>     bad class file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\company\company.jar(/Employee.class)

How can I do it...

Comment: Where are you running the command?

Comment: Why would you want to compile it a second time? You want to run it the second time using `java` no?

Comment: try: `jar jar -cf company.jar .\*.class` then `java -jar company.jar PrintEmployee.java` to run the jar

Comment: Don't execute `jar` in the same directory as the class files, do it in the parent directory of `company`

Comment: @shmosel run in C:\Users\user\Desktop\company

Comment: Be advised. Your constructor calls an overridable method, which can cause open doors to many bugs. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404369/507738).

Comment: it's fixed. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing `package` `company` in the jar file.

```
mkdir company
mv Employee.java company/
javac company/*.java
jar -cf company.jar company/*.class
```

then you can run

```
javac -cp company.jar PrintEmployee.java
```

without any problem